# How can I set off an alarm i.e. play an alarm tone in Android?

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, ringtone

I want to build an alarm application but I don't know how to set off an alarm ringtone when the alarm has gone off. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since youre Question is pretty broad and generic, I cant provide exact Code but i can point you to the things you need to do.

You need to create a [PendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) which starts a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). In the Service you need to play the Sound with a [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html). The [Media Playback](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html) Link also has a specific section on playing Sound in a Service. To schedule the PendingIntent to be fired at a certain time and start the service then, use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

Comment: Why would it be a Service and not a BroadcastReceiver?